# Modify Bibliography printing style

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

**What I want:**
A different style for my own works in the Bibliography

**What I did:** Created bibliography entries, `mywork` and `myworkimp`: *deleted on update: check below.*

**What I failed to do:** Those entries will be printed in different styles (in bold or brown colour etc).

---

### Update

After reading several other (than @samcarter's) comments in Tex.SE, I decided to switch to `biblatex`. Here's the new MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

%%%%%% This was my pre-PhD work. I will only cite it, but not put in to contribution part.
%%%%%% This will be printed in Bibliography in Brown

@mywork{myfirst,
    author    = "Myself Me",
    title     = "Very good name",
    year      = "2016",
    publisher = "N/A",
    address   = "Earth"
}

%%%%%% This is my current work and will be in contribution part.
%%%%%% This will be printed in Bibliography in Bold font
@myworkimp{mysecond,
    author    = "Myself Me",
    title     = "No Name yet!",
    year      = "2018",
    publisher = "N/A",
    address   = "Earth",
}

\end{filecontents}

%%\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress, ]{natbib} %sectionbib
\usepackage[firstinits=true,bibencoding=inputenc,hyperref=auto,refsection=chapter,backref=true,backend=biber, defernumbers=true,style=alphabetic,sorting=ynt]{biblatex}

\bibliography{\jobname} 
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

Dolor sit amet \autocite{myfirst}
Lor waht \autocite{mysecond}

\printbibliography[heading=bibnumbered]
\end{document}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This could be easy to do if you would consider switching to `biblatex`.

Comment: @samcarter There you go, mate.  :-)

Comment: BTW: `firstinits` is a deprecated option, better use `firstinits`. But good choice to switch to `biblatex`!

Comment: The options `bibencoding=inputenc,hyperref=auto,` should not be needed, they are more or less the default. `defernumbers=true,` is not needed with `style=alphabetic`, and `sorting=ynt` is unusual with `style=alphabetic`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Thanks to moewe for his useful comments to improve this answer!

If you want to keep your syntax with `@mywork` a quick hack could be to declare special `\DeclareBibliographyDriver` for these types. Disadvantage: you loose the ability to differentiate between different types of documents for your own works, in the following example I simply choose `book` for both of them (please change to an appropriate type for your work). If you need the ability to differentiate between different types, you could for example add a special keyword for your own documents, see second solution below.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

%%%%%% This was my pre-PhD work. I will only cite it, but not put in to contribution part.
%%%%%% This will be printed in Bibliography in Brown

@mywork{myfirst,
    author    = "Myself Me",
    title     = "Very good name",
    year      = "2016",
    publisher = "N/A",
    address   = "Earth"
}

%%%%%% This is my current work and will be in contribution part.
%%%%%% This will be printed in Bibliography in Bold font
@myworkimp{mysecond,
    author    = "Myself Me",
    title     = "No Name yet!",
    year      = "2018",
    publisher = "N/A",
    address   = "Earth",
}

\end{filecontents}

%%\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress, ]{natbib} %sectionbib
\usepackage[giveninits=true,bibencoding=inputenc,hyperref=auto,refsection=chapter,backref=true,backend=biber, defernumbers=true,style=alphabetic,sorting=ynt]{biblatex}


\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\DeclareBibliographyAlias{mywork}{customa}
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{customa}{%
  \usedriver{\color{brown}}{book}%
}    

\DeclareBibliographyAlias{myworkimp}{customb}
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{customb}{%
  \usedriver{\bfseries}{book}%
}   

\bibliography{\jobname} 

\begin{document}

Dolor sit amet \autocite{myfirst}
Lor waht \autocite{mysecond}

\printbibliography[heading=bibnumbered]
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Second solution using keywords**

Advantage: you can have different types for your own works, for example `mywork` could be an article and a proceeding and `myworkimp` a book.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}

%%%%%% This was my pre-PhD work. I will only cite it, but not put in to contribution part.
%%%%%% This will be printed in Bibliography in Brown

@book{myfirst,
    author    = "Myself Me",
    title     = "Very good name",
    year      = "2016",
    publisher = "N/A",
    address   = "Earth",
    keywords   = "mywork"
}

%%%%%% This is my current work and will be in contribution part.
%%%%%% This will be printed in Bibliography in Bold font
@article{mysecond,
    author    = "Myself Me",
    title     = "No Name yet!",
    year      = "2018",
    publisher = "N/A",
    address   = "Earth",
    keywords   = "myworkimp"
}

\end{filecontents*}

%%\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress, ]{natbib} %sectionbib
\usepackage[giveninits=true,bibencoding=inputenc,hyperref=auto,refsection=chapter,backref=true,backend=biber, defernumbers=true,style=alphabetic,sorting=ynt]{biblatex}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{%
    \iffieldequalstr{keywords}{mywork}{\color{brown}}{}%
    \iffieldequalstr{keywords}{myworkimp}{\bfseries}{}%
}   

\bibliography{\jobname} 

\begin{document}

Dolor sit amet \autocite{myfirst}
Lor waht \autocite{mysecond}

\printbibliography[heading=bibnumbered]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Err...! I'm having one problem with my original source file. The `bibliography` is printed like `[SMB17] bookS....` (`book` is printed at the beginning). Any idea why?

Comment: Also, `backref` is not working.

Comment: @pushpen.paul Can you show a MWE that demonstrates this problem?

Comment: Mhhh. Doesn't `\usedrivder` have two arguments? `\usedriver{initcode}{entrytype}`.

Comment: My source file is very big. It'll be difficult to make MWE from that...

Comment: @samcarter Can you elaborate on what you meant by "add a special keyword"?

Comment: @moewe Oh, yes. Thank you! This solves the problem with "book" printed in front of the entries. I did not see that. Do you have any suggestions for the content of `initcode`?

Comment: @pushpen.paul The problem with "book" is solved in the edit.

Comment: @pushpen.paul Can you take the MWE of my answer and show how you would use `backref`?

Comment: I think you can just leave the `initcode` empty, or you could move the `\bfseries` there: `\usedriver{\bfseries}{book}%` (not entirely sure if that works, but worth a try).

Comment: @pushpen.paul I added a second solution to demonstrate what I meant with keywords.

Comment: @moewe Works like a charm! Thanks for all this good suggestions!

Comment: @samcarter `keyword` solution works perfectly for `backref`... God bless you!